# How do I use DTS.Events.FireInformation() in SSIS Script Task while handling WinSCPnet.dll FileTransferProgress?

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2008, winscp-net, script-task

I have a Script Task in an SSIS (2008) package that downloads files from a remote FTP server to a local directory. The Script Task is written in C# 2008, and uses WinSCPnet.dll. Using examples from WinSCP's documentation, I came up with the script below. The script functions correctly to download the files, but all the file success/failure messages are held until the entire script completes, and then all the messages are dumped at once. File progress is not displayed at all using `Console.Write()`, and trying to use `Dts.Events.FireInformation()` in `SessionFileTransferProgress` gives me

`Error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase.Dts.get"`

Is there a way I can use the DTS.events.Fire* events to display file progress information as it happens, and file completion status after each file?

Script:

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/

using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask;
using System.AddIn;
using WinSCP;

namespace ST_3a1cf75114b64e778bd035dd91edb5a1.csproj
{
    [AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            // Setup session options
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
                HostName = (string)Dts.Variables["User::FTPServerName"].Value,
                UserName = (string)Dts.Variables["User::UserName"].Value,
                Password = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Password"].Value
            };

            try
            {
                using (Session session = new Session())
                {
                    // Will continuously report progress of transfer
                    session.FileTransferProgress += SessionFileTransferProgress;

                    session.ExecutablePath = (string)Dts.Variables["User::PathToWinSCP"].Value;

                    // Connect
                    session.Open(sessionOptions);

                    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;


                    TransferOperationResult transferResult = session.GetFiles(
                                                                                (string)Dts.Variables["User::ExportPath"].Value
                                                                                , (string)Dts.Variables["User::ImportPath"].Value
                                                                                , false
                                                                                , transferOptions
                                                                            );

                    // Throw on any error
                    transferResult.Check();

                    // Print results
                    bool fireAgain = false;
                    foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                    {
                        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, null,
                            string.Format("Download of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName),
                            null, 0, ref fireAgain);
                    }
                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Success;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, null,
                    string.Format("Error downloading file: {0}", e),
                    null, 0);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
        }

        private static void SessionFileTransferProgress(object sender, FileTransferProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            //bool fireAgain = false;


            // Print transfer progress
            Console.Write("\r{0} ({1:P0})", e.FileName, e.FileProgress);

            /*Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, null,
                            string.Format("\r{0} ({1:P0})", e.FileName, e.FileProgress),
                            null, 0, ref fireAgain);*/

            // Remember a name of the last file reported
            _lastFileName = e.FileName;
        }

        private static string _lastFileName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer I figured out was pretty simple. I changed `SessionFileTransferProgress` from `private static void` to `private void`. Once this method was no longer static, I was able to use `this` to invoke the `Dts.Events.Fire*` methods. `SessionFileTransferProgress` was changed to:

```
private void SessionFileTransferProgress(object sender, FileTransferProgressEventArgs e)
{
    bool fireAgain = false;

    this.Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, null,
                    string.Format("\r{0} ({1:P0})", e.FileName, e.FileProgress),
                    null, 0, ref fireAgain);

    // Remember a name of the last file reported
    _lastFileName = e.FileName;
}
```